# How to stop Jenkins container from dying when Jenkins is restarted from the browser?

Tags: jenkins

I used to not have this issue with the older Jenkins version that this installation replaced.

I updated to Jenkins v2.375.1 and I start it as a Docker container like this

```bash
docker run --rm -d -p 8080:8080 -v /mnt/jenkins_master/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins_master --memory=40g 1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/jenkins_master:2.375.1
```

Now when I got to my browser to restart Jenkins

```
myJenkins.domain.com/restart
```

the container dies? Why, and how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I need to start my Jenkins Docker container with a restart policy, per [Start containers automatically](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically)